# Is there a way to pull up the deleted questions by trolls when explaining the situation to junior members of the site?

Tags: discussion, support

We've been getting more frequent visitors from a particular troll, and I find it educational to be able to reference these deleted questions and answer exchanges with this particular troll. Is it possible to still access these deleted Q&A's?

Comment: Mod's superpowers (and 10 or 20K users) can get the pair for you (?), through maybe this question in the Community Bulletin could be desirable...

Comment: @Braiam slk is the 3rd highest rep user here and has a good deal more than 10k :). As far as I know, only diamond mods can see deleted questions (at least, that's the case on SU where I have >10k). 10k mods can see deleted answers, not questions. I don't have >20 anywhere yet so I don't know if that august group can see deleted questions. In any case, the point here is a way of showing the deleted stuff o new users.

Comment: @terdon I understand everything you have said (except the part where mods need also reputation, aren't they "mods"?), but one thing... just who is "slk"? I don't see him/her in the rank O_O

Comment: Well, as I just said in chat, its late here, be gentle! I meant slm obviously :). As for mods, there are diamond mods (like [mattdm](http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/users/2511/mattdm) for example) but by SE convention, users in the >10 ad >20 range are also called mods.

Comment: @terdon - have access to tools in the review tab that i can go back to 30days of deletes, but no more.

Comment: Yeah, I guess its the same I have over at SU but I can't _show_ them to anyone even I can see them myself, so that's no help.

Comment: You should be able to grab them from the SE Data Explorer.

Comment: @derobert - seems like that should've been an answer rather than a comment?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not sure any of his posts could be described as educational, but yes, you can see them as long as you have the links saved. Mods can see deleted posts on user profiles, but we've been destroying the accounts, so the profile doesn't exist anymore. I wouldn't put too much time into it; he's been a problem on other SE sites for ages, so you're probably not going to come up with anything new. Just flag the posts as spam and they'll get automatically deleted or we'll get rid of them

On a related note, don't waste your time with editing the posts, leaving comments, etc. You can if you really want to, but it's not going to help, and the post is going to end up deleted anyway

Comment: Thanks for the guidance. I spoke with Gilles earlier and he clued me in to this guy so I've been spreading the word to others as how to deal with him. We've been flagging his Q's as offensive or spam and then flagging them to be closed. I've been telling the others to close them as off-topic (leave a comment when selecting off-topic), and downvote them. Is there a better or more efficient way to help you expedite these?

Comment: I've also told the others to not edit or engage him at all in the comments. If any edits are done we've been just rolling them back so that it's more obvious it's one of his posts. They're easy to pick out once you see his pattern.